# AWS Neptune Performance

Tags: performance, http, sparql, amazon-neptune

I'm working on transferring data from our database which is a rdf store DB to AWS Neptune, and I'm facing some performance issues.

I have a `db.r4.large` Neptune instance & ec2 instance on the same vpc as Neptune.

Basically, I'm trying to ingest data to Neptune using the following http request: `<myinstance>:8182/sparql`.

Actually, I send the http request from my ec2 instance, and it seems that Neptune processing time is slow. In addition, it seems that Neptune's processing is not parallel.

Below are my tests & results:

1. I sent the following request to Neptune:

   `time curl -X POST -d @/tmp/my_file_32m.txt http://myneptune-poc.c0zm6uyrnnwp.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/sparql`

   `/tmp/my_file_32m.txt` contains sparql insert commands and the time for this request is `34.037s` while Neptune claims that it took `21.846 s`:

   > ```
   > {
   > "type" : "Commit",
   > "totalElapsedMillis" : 21846
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > **`real    0m34.037s`** 
   >   `user    0m0.044s` 
   >   `sys    0m0.062s`

   A `tcpdump` can clearly proves that the response from Neptune was received in a delay of 34 seconds.
2. When I sent a data of 100m it took more than 1 min.
3. When I sent the same file of 32m in parallel, time was multiple in 2 :

   `time xargs -I % -P 8 curl -vX POST -d @/tmp/my_file_32m.txt "http://myneptune-poc.c0zm6uyrnnwp.us-east-1.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/sparql" < <(printf '%s\n' {1..2})<`

   > ```
   > {
   > "type" : "Commit",
   > "totalElapsedMillis" : 29797
   > }
   > {
   > "type" : "Commit",
   > "totalElapsedMillis" : 30362
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > **`real    0m57.752s`** 
   >   `user    0m0.137s` 
   >   `sys    0m0.101s`

   I took a `tcpdump` and clearly see from the `wireshark` that the request was sent in parallel, but there is a delay of ~1 min till Neptune returned `200 OK` for both requests.

   Actually, it seems that Neptune's processing is not concurrent.

   request was sent in time 12 and `200 ok` for both requests was sent in time 69 which is exactly 57 seconds of delay.
4. I tried to increase my Neptune instance size to `db.r4.xlarge` and also to `db.r4.2xlarge`, db, but I got the same performance.
5. I tried to send a compressed data in a `gzip` format in order to improve times, but it seems that Neptune doesn't support it (checking in `wireshark` the request was sent correctly).

I would like to hear your opinion about my tests and the results:

1. why performance is slow for a single http request?
2. why Neptune's processing is not parallel?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask this the Amazon Neptune support? Afaik, this is a commercial product, neither implementation details nor any details about datastructures, query optimizers, indexes etc. are online. Especially a *why* question like , *"why Neptune's processing is not parallel?"* - who else than the devs can answer this question correctly, i.e. without any guesses?

Comment: I asked this question also in aws forum, but I published also here in order to see if someone else also faced the same issue.

Comment: Ok, then it's always good to mention cross-site postings - could also be used as future reference if you'll get an answer there.

Comment: Hi, do you have any update on this?

Comment: I opened a ticket to aws and they are investigating my data.currently,the rate on my server is 10000records/sec.I had a meeting with aws team and they recommended to increase my instance size to 8xlarge and run load api on files with size that are more than giga,but it didn't help.so I will update the thread once my ticket be resolved..

Comment: Checking in on this to see if you had any other update since Jan.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing the output of `time` (client side round trip time) with server reported `totalEllapsedMillis`. The former includes your network transmission time where as the latter is just the time that the db took to compute the query from the time it accepted the request. Do you have any metrics on the time it took to transmit your 100MB file?

Neptune does process queries in parallel (in fact the amount of parallelism scales with your instance type). If your queries are really small compared to the time it spends on the wire, then it may appear like the results completed one after the other. I would like to see more granular details of your experiments to see if there is an issue with your setup.

For starters, what is the network lag between your client and the DB endpoint? (ie how long does it take for you to make a request to the /status API for example)